# How to handle Typescript Generics when using styled function from '@mui/material/styles'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

```
import Table,{TableProps} from 'my/table/path'

const StyledTable = styled(Table)({
  ...my styles
})

const AnotherTable = <T, H>(props: TableProps<T, H>) => {
  return <StyledTable {...props} />
}
```

This is my error message:

```
Types of parameters 'item' and 'item' are incompatible.
          Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'T'.
            'unknown' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'unknown'.
```

It seems that my generic was not carried over when using `styled` because when I do it like this:

```
const AnotherTable = <T, H>(props: TableProps<T, H>) => {
  return <Table {...props} />
}
```

it does not return any error and my generics are working

Comment: please share reproducible example

Comment: did you find solution? I face same issue as yours

Comment: @Akza sorry I posted my answer

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I solved it. Basically all I did was explicitly infer the type after it was created.

```
const StyledTable = styled(Table)({
  ...my styles
}) as typeof Table;
```

Comment: What if I want to omit some of the props?